# What can be used for a .net application to control video files (especially mts and m2ts)?

Tags: .net, video, mts

I am trying to build an application which will be used for analysing video files; pause, play, slow forward/backward, go to time and get time.

I am trying to use MediaElement for Wpf. But it does not support slowing down the movie for some file types (like MTS, that I will use a lot).

What is the best way, or best control, or best library for this?

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7 .MTS files are readable through DirectShow via Media Foundation's `MFSourceFilter` and `Media Foundation MP2demux` filters (chances are that they can also be played through Media Foundation directly), and so you can play and otherwise control them through [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net) library.

Support for container formats and encodings depend on availability of underlying components, such as filters, including stock and third party, capable of dealing with these formats.